# How to start a standalone angular service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a service that watches something on the rootscope and does something in response. Nobody else requires that service as a dependency. How do I tell the service to start doing its thing?

This is how I do it for now.

```
angular.module('app')
.service('myService', function ($rootScope) {

  return function () {
      $rootScope.$on("...", function () {
        //do stuff
      });
    };

})
.run(function (myService) {
  myService();
});
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I don't think it can get cleaner than that...

Comment: I'm the OP. Now that I've lived with this self-starting service for a while I'd recommend against the idea. Having a service that kicks-in on its own may interfere with unit tests for other services. I think it's better to have an `application-start.js` where you manually start all these services. That file would be in your real app (`index.html`), but not in your tests (`karma.config.js`).

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented similar things, but using a directive, and not a service:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.$on('myEvent', function () {
         // Do stuff
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And then used this in the root element of my application, which can, for example, be `body`:

```
<body ng-app="app" my-directive>
```

The benefit of using directives in this way over services is that it makes it a touch less global / final. For example, if you end up wanting some scopes to not be able to `$emit` events to this handler, then you could move the `myDirective` to another element. Or you could maybe down the road you'll want a part of your app to respond slightly differently to `myEvent`, so you can add another instance of `myDirective`, maybe passing it some options via attributes. On the whole it leaves it a lot more open to adding complex behaviour.